# как обработать переменные внутри регулярного выражения

Tags: php

есть произвольный текст с картинками, 
нужно картинки обработать с помощью регулярного выражения.
внутри регулярного выражения требуется проверить дату добавления файла, вот тут загвоздка...

```
$ content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <img src="https://example.com/img/img.jpg" 
alt="image" width="550" height="318"> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';



$content = preg_replace('/(<img.*) src(.*?)=(.*?)"(.*?)(img.*?)(\.)(.*?)(".*?)alt=(.*?)width=(.*?)height=(.*?) \/(>)/',

'<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "author": "Company",
  "contentUrl": "$2$3$4$5$6$7, //тут все работает
  "datePublished": "'.date ("Y-m-d", 
filemtime(utf8_decode('$2$3$4$5$6$7'))).'", //вот тут выходит ошибка, т.к. переменные регулярного выражения не обрабатываются. 
//как исправить эту ситуацию?
  "name": $9
}
</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

реализовал через функцию preg_replace_callback()